# Plotting a Map within a Map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot

I'm brand new to any programming and I'm starting right in the deep end with R!

So, I'm trying to plot a map of some dive sites from which me and a buddy collected some data, which are off the west coast of the Isla de Juventud. I have plotted the map of Cuba and a more zoomed in one of the Island in R, and what I'm hoping to achieve is something along the lines of the following, but I just chucked this together with paint so obviously it would be better quality produced in R.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xve973hvih1vw77/OZ-gGpDgsJ <- this link

The code I have for the cuba map and the island map is this, respectively.

```
map("worldHires", xlim=c(-85.3198254, -73.718262), ylim=c(190663280, 23.5), fill=TRUE, col="darkseagreen3", bgcol="grey80") map.axes()
```

and

```
map("worldHires", xlim=c(-83.25, -82.5), ylim=c(21.4, 22), fill=TRUE, col="darkseagreen3", bg="gray80") rect(-83.2, 21.5, -83.15, 21.65, border="red")
```

I'd rather learn how to do it or where I'm going wrong, if anywhere, here as I really want to improve my skills with this program.

Comment: This may be a start: http://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-maps-with-insets/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing this the wrong way.

I read the manual for R package Maps in (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/maps.pdf), and I couldn't find a map database called "worldHires"

To have a better understanding, try the commands

```
map('world2')
map.axes()
```

This should give a plot of the world map; however, to highlight certain cities, read about `map.cities` command in the package manual.

To get a map of Cuba for example try this

```
map("world2", region='Cuba',fill=TRUE, col="darkseagreen3")
map.axes()
```

I hope this helps

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply :)
The "worldHires" command is a hi-res world map, and then I used coordinates to get cuba and the island.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded maps, mapdata, and maptools? That fixed the same problem for me!